# How to verify file type for multipart/form data upload in vertx?

Tags: vert.x

I have a multipart/form with file upload in my Vert.x web application.
The issue I am running into is that I can only seem to validate the type of the uploaded file after having the request go through Vertx's `BodyHandler`.

Now I can validate the type after it went through, but the `BodyHandler` has already uploaded the file at this point in time. On a similair issue it was stated that you should check the content-type with your own handler before the `BodyHandler`, but this always returns an empty `formAttributes`.

I've tried creating my own handler:

```
  public void handle(RoutingContext context) {

    context.request().setExpectMultipart(true);

    MultiMap attributes = context.request().formAttributes();
    System.out.println(attributes);

    context.next();

  }
```

But `attributes` is always empty, so I can't verify the content-type of the file uploaded.

After it passes through the `BodyHandler` into my other handler it works fine:

```
      MultiMap attributes = context.request().formAttributes();
      Set<FileUpload> uploads = context.fileUploads();
      for (FileUpload file : uploads
           ) {
        System.out.println(file.contentType());
        // This returns image/jpeg
      }

      context.response().end();
```

But as I stated above, the file is already uploaded when it has passed through the `BodyHandler`.

Here is the code for the handlers:

```
router.post("/api/someendpoint").handler(new FileTypeHandler());
router.post("/api/someendpoint").handler(BodyHandler.create()
      .setUploadsDirectory("static/images")
      .setBodyLimit(MB * 1));
router.post("/api/someendpoint").handler(new EndPointHandler());
```

How can I verify the type of a file being uploaded before it passes through the `BodyHandler`, so that I can reject any other file upload except an image?

Comment: What's the problem with having file uploaded before inspecting content? You can configure the `BodyHandler` to clean up uploads after request with `setDeleteUploadedFilesOnEnd`

Comment: @tsegismont I was aiming to avoid the work of uploading the file when it is an invalid file type. With `setDeleteUploadedFilesOnEnd`, is there an easy way to only delete the files if certain condition is true (e.g. if invalid file extension)?

Comment: No, with `setDeleteUploadedFilesOnEnd` any uploaded file will be deleted when request processing ends. Then in your route handler you may copy valid files to another directory if archiving is a requirement.